# SharePoint 2013 Visual Studio 2015 Workflow Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager, visual-studio-2015

I have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise vesion. Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate Version. Topology as below

1. SQL01 (Clustered)
2. SQL02 (Clustered)
3. FE01  (load balance)
4. FE02  (load balance)
5. APP01
6. APP02

SharePoint access by http://xyz.company.com and I have installed Workflow Manager on FE01 and join other servers in farm (i.e. FE02 & APP02)

I have register workflow on http as below

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite 'http://xyz.company.com' -WorkflowHostUri 'http://xyz.company.com:12991' -AllowOAuthHttp -Force
```

I have also configure below services on my farm
[image]

Now I can see SharePoint 2013 Workflow option in my SharePoint Designer also.

But now the Issue is when I create workflow in Visual Studio and try to deploy I will get below error,So what I did is I go to Central Admin and deploy it manually and Activate Feature from Manage Site Feature of SharePoint which will not give me error. But workflow will not associate with List

[image]

But same project when I deploy in my single box development server than I will not get any error for activation plus it will get associate with List automatically. What can be issue with my production environment. Do I am missing something.

Comment: Any help on this please?

Comment: if you click on the Worfklow service app proxy, is it says connected? also from the Manage Web application, click on the Web application from ribbon click on the Service connection, make sure WF is assoicate with it

Comment: It is showing connected and Service association is also there

Comment: Workflow Manager installed on all server or only one Server? if one, did you install the WFM client on all other sharepoint server?

Comment: Yes it is installed on all the server, but still I will check again once I will reach in office

Comment: Ok I check myself in all the server it is installed